# Extend Sitecore insert link functionality

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, insert, icons, sitecore

I have an issue which I don't quite know how to approach.

I need to extend the Sitecore Insert link functionality: when I insert a link to a Sitecore Item, a certain icon, based on some logic (I've already created the logic for another user story(*)), needs to appear in the front of the link after "Insert" button is pressed, and of course, finally on the UI.

I was thinking on the following approach: after the item is inserted, the item's ID is sent to the backend via an Ajax call and the response is a mark-up with the values returned by the service I told you above at (*).

The issue is that I don't know where to start on or if my idea is ok.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

In the RichText Commands.js file, I have added the following script which sends the item Sitecore ID to the API:

```
function scInsertSitecoreLink(sender, returnValue) {
   if (!returnValue) {
        return;
    }

    var url = returnValue.url;
    var itemId = url.substring(url.indexOf("=") + 1, url.lastIndexOf("&"));

    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: '/sitecore/api/Test/ThisIsTheTestApiCall',
        data: JSON.stringify(itemId),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {  
            alert(result);  
        }        
    });

    [...]
}
```

1. First I have added var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); before the ajax call;
   More info here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/
2. Then I've checked if there are any changes over the routes: RegisterHttpRoutes;
3. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better to modify the `renderField` pipeline, because if you ever need to change these icons later, you're going to have to process every single link on your site.

To do that, you'll want to create a processor and have it run before `Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.ExpandLinks, Sitecore.Kernel` in the `renderField` pipeline so that you can use the dynamic links (which contain IDs) to figure out what icons you need. From there you can use HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument to find and update the markup when the link is rendered.